# Prove that $\sqrt{101}$ lies between $10$ and $10.05$ by Mean Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\sqrt{101}$ lies between $10$ and $10.05$ by Mean Value Theorem.
Maybe Lagrange's MVT will be required here.
But I am very eager about the process.

Comment: What values does $x^2$ take on the interval $[10..10.05]$?

Comment: $10.05^2=101.0025$...not sure what else there is to say.  Is it possible you meant to write "Intermediate Value Theorem"?

Comment: $$10\leq \sqrt{101} = 10 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{100}} \leq 10\left(1+\frac{1}{200}\right)= 10+\frac{1}{20}$$ since $\sqrt{1+x}\leq 1+\frac{x}{2}$ for any $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt x$. Then by the Mean Value Theorem for some $c\in (100,101)$ we have

$f^{'}(c)=\frac{f(101)-f(100)}{101-100}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2\sqrt c}=\sqrt{101}-10\Rightarrow\sqrt{101}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt c}+10$.

Now since $c\in (100,101)$,

$\frac{1}{2\sqrt c}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt {100}}=0.05$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the MVT to the function $\sqrt x$:
$$
\sqrt{101}-\sqrt{100}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt c}\,(101-100),\quad 100<c<101.
$$